# Branch cut contour integral - contour understanding

Tags: complex-numbers, contour-integration, residue-calculus, branch-cuts

Im trying to understand the contour when there are two poles on the real axis without poles on Im axis,
because their residue cancle each other.

[contour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTyEJ.png)

$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{(x+1)^2(x+2)}$$

For residue of pole $(-2)=-1$, residue of pole $(-1)=-1$.

Comment: The residue at $-1$ is $0$, not $-1$. The contour in your image is unrelated to this integral, so why don't try finding the right contour instead?

Comment: With “your” contour you can add a $\displaystyle x^{\nu}$-factor in the denominator. Take $\displaystyle\nu \to 0$ at the very end.

Comment: ... or put $\log x$ into the numerator (and follow [this approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#Example_4_%E2%80%93_branch_cuts)).

Answer (score 1):

When we use a contour in the complex plane to evaluate real integrals of rational functions, and the integrand has poles in the real axis, they must be first-order poles only because there is a technique to calculate the integral, but the integral doesn't exist if the order of the pole is 2 or greater.

Moreover, contour integration in the complex plane is used when it's hard to find an antiderivative of the function, or when it can't be written in terms of standard functions.

I suggest you use partial-fraction decomposition:

$$\frac{1}{(x+1)^2(x+2)} = \frac{1}{x+2} - \frac{1}{x+1} + \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$$

and then evaluate the improper integral with the fractions on the right hand side. I hope you can work it out from here!